# IIS rewrites URL even if I comment the rewrite rule on web.config

Tags: asp.net, iis, url-rewriting, web-config

I have a Web Site Project which has a web.config where I usually comment this bunch of rows, just to avoid HTTPS redirect applied in the production environment:

```
<system.webServer>

[...]

<!--<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="false">
      <match url="(.*)"/>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://mywebsite.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>-->

</system.webServer>
```

Even if the snippet is commented, during Debug I am redirected from http://localhost:53435/ to https://mywebsite.com/ **on my Dev machine.**

**This behaviour doesn't occur on other Dev PCs.**

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a 301 redirection code, which browser keeps in it memory.

Just try it in private browsing/incognito mode.

If the issue resolved clear in private browsing/incognito mode, then clear your browser cache to revolve this in normal mode.